# Sails js v1.1 using two front end "controllers" parasails error (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sails.js

In a previous project with Sails version (0.12), I divided my layout.ejs file to manage a top bar and footer separately from the body.
It looked like

```
<%- partial('./partials/topnav.ejs') %>
<!-- begin::Body -->
<%- body %>
<!-- end:: Body -->
<%- partial('./partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

I was using AngularJS. The top bar was wrapped in a controller, and the body was wrapped in a different one. Basically in the partials, the code looked like

```
<div ng-controller="topnavCtrl" ng-cloak>
    //My topnav code
</div>
```

...

```
 <div ng-controller="aPageCtrl" ng-cloak>
    //My page code
 </div>
```

I thought I could do something similar with Sails js 1.1, started with option 1 for Web App, but because it's not AngularJS but Vue.js and the parasails, I have no idea how to fix the error I'm getting :

> Whoops An unexpected client-side error occurred. Cannot load page
>   script (`topnav) because a page script has already been loaded on this
>   page. Please check your browser's JavaScript console for further
>   details. This message will not be displayed in production. If you're
>   unsure, ask for help. Mon Mar 04 2019 16:32:05 GMT-0500 (EST)

And the browser console says :

> [Error] Error: Cannot load page script (`topnav) because a page script
>   has already been loaded on this page.     registerPage
>   (parasails.js:710:156)    Global Code (topnav.page.js:1)

My topnav partials have

```
<div id="topnav" v-cloak>
    //My topnav code
</div>
```

If I remove the `<div id="mypage" v-cloak>` from my "body" page, the error is gone.

Obviously, it has something to do with Parasails, but is there a way to use two "controllers" for a page in sails v1 ?
(I call them controllers because in Sails 0.12 with AngularJS they were called controller, now I just have no idea what they are !)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to this with out issue in Sails V1.

What you had initially should still work:

```
<%- partial('./partials/topnav.ejs') %>
<!-- begin::Body -->
<%- body %>
<!-- end:: Body -->
<%- partial('./partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

Though its suggested you name your files `footer.partial.ejs`

Your partials dont need to be wrapped in a controller you can simply call them based on a class or id, which ever you prefer.

Also on your partial's `.ejs` file you dont want to have 'v-clock' on it because that should already exist on your individual `.ejs` files.

So:

```
<div id="topNav">
 //top nav code
</div>

<div id="homepage" v-clock>
  <%- partial('../../partials/topnav.partial.ejs') %>
 //homepage code
</div>
```

Note that since your injecting your partials into layout you wont need to add it on each page. I just wanted to show a clear example.

Comment: Also as a side note you could consider moving your top-nav in to a component rather then a partial.

Comment: Ok, but when I do so, I have the following error : `[Error] Error: Cannot load page script ('topnav) because a page script has already been loaded on this page. registerPage (parasails.js:710:156) Global Code (topnav.page.js:1)` do you know what is causing it ?

Comment: Ohh hmm yeah it looks like parasails doesnt let you call two views on one page. So I think your best bet is to move your nav into a component.

Comment: So... to do that, do I only have to replace `parasails.registerPage('topnav', {...` by `parasails.registerComponent('topNav', {...` ?

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work, I don't know how to work with Components.

Comment: It doesnt work quite like that. I made a post for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010131/sails-js-how-to-move-the-top-nav-to-a-component/55010148#55010148

Comment: Sorry I don't have the rep to comment in your post. `$ sails generate component topnav` gives me the following error : `error: No generator called 'component' found.
Did you mean 'sails generate api component'?

Tip: Want to use a custom or community generator?
Add it to your app's .sailsrc file under 'modules':
You can use a relative path: [...]
`

Comment: Oh dang your right I guess I was thinking about helpers. Let me update that post

Comment: I'm not sure about this... my top nav is my top menu for my whole app, with some code protected for the admin/logged-in user. Putting the ejs code as a template in the component seems pretty not safe to me :/

Comment: Also, how do you add the component in your html ? <topnav></topnav> doesn't show my menu XD

Comment: Why do you think it's not safe?

Comment: the tag is whatever you named your component so if you named it `assets/js/components/tophat.js` then you use `<tophat></tophat>`

Comment: Because if anyone look at the topnav.component.js file of the app with a browser inspect tool, the html/ejs template code from the component is visible, so the `<% if(me) { %> protected admin menu < } %>` that I don't want normal users to see will show up...

Comment: Hmm my file is `assets/js/components/topnav.component.js`and neither `<topnav>` nor `<topnav.component>` from the layout file works (I would have to add it plus some style div manually, in all of my pages which I really don't want to.)