# Sails.js- how to move the Top nav to a component?

Tags: components, sails.js, navbar

I needed a top-nav with a good amount of extras and flexabliltiy. I also didnt want my `layout.ejs` to become a tangled mess. So I moved my top-nav into a component and wanted to share how I did it here.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a new component in `assest/js/components/` 
  (I look at the existing components that come with the Sails app for reference) I named mine `masthead`
- Built my nav-bar in the component
- Removed any mention of the top-nav in `layout.ejs`
- Added `<masthead></masthead>` to all HTML files that will have this top-nav

This also has the added benefit of being able to get your Sails_Locals on to your nav-bar.

Answer (score 0):

@Raqem maybe you could write one for how to use a Vue plugin in Parasails :-)